# navbar shows up only after scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have written css and html for this simple page. But whenever i open the page it does not show me navbar but on scrolling down it starts showing me navbar. I am unable to find out what could be the possible cause of this as there is css property that says that navbar will remain transparent. I am using bootstrap 4

[image: On opening this picture shows up]

[image: On scrolling down navbar becomes visible]

Here is my some of my css code for navbar

```css
#mainNav {
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: rgb(93, 93, 93) !important;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Merriweather Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000 !important;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #6c757d;
  font-family: "Merriweather Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover, #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:active {
  color: #0f1010 !important;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.active {
  color: #0f1010 !important;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #0f1010 !important;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.7) !important;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #000000 !important;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.7) !important;
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    color: #000000 !important;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item:last-child .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-scrolled {
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-scrolled .navbar-brand {
    color: #212529;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-scrolled .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #f4623a;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-scrolled .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #212529;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-scrolled .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    color: #f4623a;
  }
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top py-3" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Volunteer</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Explore Events</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">How it works</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Locations</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: This is not a working example because the nav is there on page load, and theres not enough content on the page to scroll

Comment: If you could provide a WORKING example then I will be able to find the issue. I dont recommend Piyush Teraiya's answer because that will only mask what the issue is. Dont add code to override something you dont need but cant find, find what it is you dont need and either remove it or change it. Like I said if you post a working demo I might be able to find it

Comment: @Chillin' i was able to solve it. Thanks for your consideration :) and actually my css was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #navbar {
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: -62px;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      transition: top 0.3s;
    }
    
    #navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    #navbar a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      float: right;
    }
    
    ul li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Volunteer</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Explore Events</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">How it works</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Locations</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mollis lectus ullamcorper feugiat tristique. Sed fermentum libero dignissim, congue ex quis, tristique velit. Curabitur placerat finibus odio, vitae malesuada metus feugiat sit amet.
      Etiam feugiat ligula nisi, sed blandit libero sollicitudin vel. Sed molestie scelerisque orci, ut elementum neque pretium id. Quisque leo lorem, laoreet sit amet pharetra vulputate, aliquam nec est. Praesent in mauris ut odio maximus feugiat. Donec
      quis volutpat metus, eu commodo arcu. Aenean odio ipsum, sagittis in magna in, dictum suscipit mi. Donec rhoncus a risus at rutrum. Morbi eu purus tellus. Pellentesque eget tellus ac nulla porta scelerisque. Donec ut velit nulla. Vivamus semper
      vel enim sed iaculis. Quisque ut elementum urna. Mauris pellentesque erat vel magna volutpat vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam luctus nulla risus, sed faucibus odio tristique a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
      aliquam magna at libero cursus, eu feugiat leo ornare. Etiam pellentesque libero vitae mollis tempor. Donec lacinia, orci nec venenatis vulputate, diam leo auctor magna, ac tempus sem purus a libero.</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
    window.onscroll = function() {
      scrollFunction()
    };

    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-62px";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```